# Can't install kivy. Fail Building wheel for kivy (pyproject.toml)

Tags: pip, kivy, python-wheel, toml

I've somehow screwed up either my pip or my kivy files. I cant install either. I've tried `pip install kivy` and also `git clone https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git --depth 1`

I'm on a macos Monterey 12.6.1
python 3.11`

I start with:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ pip install kivy
```

It gets hung up on the building wheel for kivy pyproject.toml.

```
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./myvenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy) (2022.9.24)
Building wheels for collected packages: kivy
  Building wheel for kivy (pyproject.toml) ... -
```

Then  the end of the error code looks like:

```
kivy/core/image/img_imageio.c:438:62: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber'
        #define __Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber(frame, lineno)  (frame)->f_lineno = (lineno)
                                                            ~~~~~~~^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/pytypedefs.h:22:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct _frame'
      typedef struct _frame PyFrameObject;
                     ^
      2 warnings and 1 error generated.
       error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
Failed to build kivy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for kivy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
(
```

I'm at a complete lost. I've tried to uninstall and reinstall packages, I've done `pip install wheel` , and `pip install clang` both recommended from other SO posts.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem so I asked on the Kivy Discord and I was told that there is no wheel for kivy on Python 3.11 yet.
I was told to build it from source and that worked.
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#kivy-source-install

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git
cd kivy
python3.11 -m pip install cython
python3.11 setup.py build_ext --inplace
make install
```

It is best to do this in a virtual environment

```
python3.11 -m virtualenv <Environment Name>
cd <Environment Name>
source bin/activate
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now, February 2023, there are two alternatives to this problem in macOS. Possibly works the same for Windows, I don't know. The first is shown above and can be described as "building your own wheel" for Python 3.11. That approach did not work for me as my installation crashed at the "make install" line with error messages about xcode. The second alternative, which worked for me, was to install the most recent version of Python for which Kivy already had a wheel buuilt. In my case, I installed Python3.10. After i installed Python3.10, the Kivy installtion instructions at [www.kivy.org](http://www.kivy.org) worked flawlessly.

Python 3.10 has a installer package at [www.python.org](http://www.python.org) so its easy to install. In my case, the installer package modified my .bash_profile file so that python3.10 was inserted into my PATH.

In my case, Python3.10 was the most recent version of Python installed on my machine. If Python 3.10 is not the most recent version on your computer, then you may encounter problems. Different applications on your computer may use different releases of Python. The Python installer may change your PATH variables to point only at the Python 3.10 installation.

I suspect that the "build your own wheel" issue is common with Kivy installtions because Kivy always lags behind Python. Python will release Python 3.12 and it will be a while, months I would guess, before Kivy catches up. So that means if you keep your Python install always up-to-date then you will center encounter the need to "build your own wheel".

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install kivy -c conda-forge
```

Do not use pip to install kivy if you’re using Anaconda, unless you’re installing from source.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#kivy-source-install

Answer (score 0):

All what you need to do is installing `cython`.

```
% pip3 install cython
```

Then reinstall kivymd

```
% pip3 install kivymd
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, the virtual environment will reflect the version of Python used to create it. Therefore, install Python3.10 to get the most recent kivy wheel.

Using [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python@3.10) or other mechanisms, install Python 3.10. Homebrew is your friend for MacOS.

Then using that version of Python as the command:

```
$ python3.10 -m venv myvenv  
$ . ./myenv/bin/activate  
$ pip install -U    pip wheel  
$ pip install kivy[full]
```

This worked for me, MacOS Monterey 12.6.4