# Is Kivy installation possible today without building your own wheel?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, kivy

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74384501/cant-install-kivy-fail-building-wheel-for-kivy-pyproject-toml)

shows that in order to install Kivy with python3.11, you must build your own "wheel". Unfortunately for me, the above install fails at the "make install" command. "which python" seems to confirm that i am in the correct virtual environment, but i am not certain.

So we know for sure that if, as of today, you have the most recent version of python, which is python3.11, then you must build your own wheel for Kivy.

That stackoverflow link doesnt work for me, so I thought, well I will just install python3.7 or python3.8. Unfortunately [www.python.org](http://www.python.org) does not have installers for versions lower than 3.9. [www.python.org](http://www.python.org) does have python3.7 and python3.8 available but those versions do not have "macOS 64-bit...installer" available for them. i am reluctant to try a python install manually without the installer.

my reading of the Kivy documentation confirms that Kivy is happy with python3.7 or python3.8.

So for me, because I want to use a python version that has an installer on [www.python.org](http://www.python.org), I cannot install Kivy without building my own wheel. And that installation fails for me.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES, Kivy installation is possible today without building your own wheel. Use python3.10 as of today, February 8, 2023. Kivy wheels are already built for phthon3.10. I installed Python3.10 from [www.python.org](http://www.python.org) on my mac laptop running Monterey 12.6. Then I followed the Kivy install instructions at [www.kivy.org](http://www.kivy.org). The instructions worked perfectly and now I can run Kivy apps from the command line. Next step is to synchronize my python IDE with the environment variables that were used to install Python3.10 and Kivy.